# What's the general form of a homogeneous ODE (linear or not, of any order)?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

To my understanding (from reading Wikipedia) the general form of homogeneous first order ODE is
$$
h(x,y)\frac{dy}{dx}=g(x,y)
$$
where $h$ and $g$ are both homogeneous functions of the same degree, for example, the following equation that I just made up
$$
x^2\frac{dy}{dx}-\frac{y^4}{xy+x^2}=0
$$
would have both $h$ and $g$ be of homogeneous functions degree 2 and therefore homogeneous.

What about higher than first order? I'm guessing 2nd order homogeneous ODE would take the form of
$$
f(x,y)\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+h(x,y)\frac{dy}{dx}+g(x,y)=0
$$
where $f, g, h$ are all homogeneous to the same order.

When I tried to look this up, the result always is "Second order homogeneous linear". Is this because for second order ODEs, the classification of homogeneous isn't useful enough on its own without also being linear? If it's not this then why?

Thanks.

Comment: Pretty much, yeah. For sure, homogeneity is an important quality on its own, but differential equations are discussed mostly in terms of their order and linearity. Linearity is especially important as it allows us to use the tools of linear algebra

Comment: Actually, the point of "homogeneous" as in "homogeneous first order DE" is invariance under simultaneous scaling $x \mapsto c x$, $y \mapsto c y$.  That kind of scaling does not leave $d^2 y/dx^2$ invariant, so for $f(x,y) \dfrac{d^2 y}{dx^2} + h(x,y) \dfrac{dy}{dx} + g(x,y) = 0$ you'd need $f(x,y)$ of one degree higher than $g(x,y)$ and $h(x,y)$.  But in fact I don't think homogeneous (in this sense) second order equations are much studied.